# NSDate formatting for some date is not the valid date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

currently I have a piece of code that is converting a set of string (eg. 900130) keyed in by user to a date using yyMMdd(Malaysia IC) format. My code for converting the string as follows:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyMMdd"];
date = [dateFormat dateFromString:temp]; // temp = string key in by user
```

The problem didn't occur to me when I was running some test, but when I gave it to someone else to test it, the problem occur where the string 490130 which should be converted to 30/1/1949 was converting it to 30/1/2049.

How do I convert 490130 to 30/1/1949 instead of 30/1/2049

Comment: What cutoff do you want for your 2-digit year to be considered 19xx versus 20xx?

Comment: Add 100 years to the date?

Comment: or subtract 100 years from the date.

Comment: @rmaddy maybe i should add a checking to compare is it over the current year.. hmm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDateFormatter` assumes 20xx for a 2-digit year if the year is less than 50 and 19xx for a 2-digit year if the year is greater than 50. I forget which it assumes when the year is 50.

It seems you want a cutoff different from 50. There is no built-in support for using a different cutoff.

One option is to look at the first two characters and see if it is below or after your cutoff. Then prepend either 19 or 20 to the start of the string as needed. Then parse the string using `yyyyMMdd`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the date formatter. I had solved my problem by checking for current year and the year keyed in to manually add "19" or "20" to the front of the string and parsing the string as yyyyMMdd